# Approval - sharePoint 2013 Template Missing?

Tags: workflow, 2013, sharepoint-designer

I installed SharePoint Server 2013 in my development environment and using the web platform installer 4.0 i done the workflow configuration. After that I checked workflow service Application, there i found installed successfully.

My issue is when I plan to create workflow in OOB there I saw only sharepoint2010 workflow templates, so how to update SharePoint 2013 templates and in the SharePoint designer 2013 there also start approval process workflow action is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you installed SP2013 & then Workflow Manager 1.0 using the WebPI, correct?

Where are you looking for the "templates"? Within the browser? OOTB only the 2010 templates are there. If you open SPD2013 you can create 2013 style workflows. If you are using VS2012 you need the Office Developer Tools for VS2012 (available via the WebPI as well). VS2013 includes all the tools and templates needed to create workflows in the base install.

Comment: Am also facing the same issue, even after  installing n configuring wf manager and wf manager client in my server farm and creating wf service application proxy successfully and after running the  register-spworkflowservice powershellcmdlet , am still not able to see the sp 2013 wf template in my sp d 2013 .what may be the issue ?what step am missing ? pls help

Answer (score 0):

I am trying hard to understand what exactly is the problem here - do you not see the option of creating a SharePoint 2013 Workflow in SharePoint Designer?

If so, did you make sure to register your site collection using the **Register-SPWorkflowService** command?

[More info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588%28v=office.15%29.aspx#section5)